# Is bundling my JS/TS project anti-pattern?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I'm working on a project in Angular 2 using TypeScript and trying to nail-down my workflow.

Yesterday, I saw [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=szJjsduHBQQ) from Guy Bedford about package management. In it, he makes mention of the fact that he considers bundling to be anti-pattern.

I've seen similar mention of moving away from bundling on an [angular-university guide](http://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-run-angular-2-in-production-today/#isthebundlesizearealconcern).

From what I have read since watching the video, it seems to me that the reason for bundling being anti-pattern is that [HTTP2 allows multiple responses per request](https://www.igvita.com/2013/06/12/innovating-with-http-2.0-server-push/), sent in parallel. This seems pretty useful since a single request to your server could return the whole angular app in individual files.

Is HTTP2 support now prevalent enough to transition to un-bundled apps? What are the pros and cons?

EDIT #2: tried to make the question more focused

Comment: Y'know, I knew a few different opinion about files concatenation vs http2.
In general http2 is better. It's a future anyway.

But at the moment it's still not perfect and in some cases may be slower then http1+concatenation. And of course there is a little bit about compatibility.

Comment: HTTP2 is purely theoretical for now and for a long time to come. Until a satisfactory percentage of your users are going to support HTTP2 you are forced to bundle your JS "the old fashioned way". Also, besides reducing the number of requests, bundling has other advantages too if you're using commonjs.

Comment: This question (as written) is an opinion question. The naive rephrasing to make it less of one ("what are some considerations in weighing http2 vs bundling") is arguably too broad (or still opinion-based). If it were me I would ask two (or more) separate questions with the first being "Why would Guy Bedford call bundling an anti-pattern in this video?"

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv purely theoretical? Its supported in 90+% of browsers (by market share) http://caniuse.com/#feat=http2

Comment: @JaredSmith seems like an arbitrary distinction to make since the answer would be the same, but I take your point. Given Sergiu's response above, I think I'll just shelve this question for now since it's not overly important.

Comment: @Askanison4 see my response to sergiu. Its quite relevant unless you're stuck in IE land.

Comment: @JaredSmith I've updated the question in the hopes of getting more of a discussion. Please feel free to suggest improvements

Comment: I find that browser caches and CDN caches are more of an impact for a (regular) user. If unbundling helps leveraging these caches (i.e. most resources did not change), then unbundling should be used. HTTP/2 makes unbundling a "no brainer" since it multiplexes requests (on first load)

Comment: @JaredSmith Browser support is only half of the equation, right? Servers have to serve HTTP2 in order for this to work.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan fair enough, but devs have a lot more control over choice of server than choice of client.

Comment: @JaredSmith I stand corrected. IE10 dropped under 1%. So overall it's safe to use HTTP2. Sorry for misleading.

Comment: In [FOSDEM: So that was HTTP/2, what's next?](https://fosdem.org/2017/schedule/event/mozilla_http2_whats_next/?utm_source=dev-newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=mar2-2017) Daniel Stenberg briefly talks about HTTP/2, where it gives you benefits, where it still falls short (packet loss etc) and what they are up to now/next. If you have spare ~20min of your life, IMHO (despite quite lousy audio quality) it is worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anti-pattern is a strong term. Its also a somewhat fuzzy one: we all have this intuitive sense of what it means, but it is certainly easy to get lost in the weeds of arguing whether questionable practice x is or is not, in fact, an anti-pattern.

So rather than trying to read too much into an off-hand comment during a talk from a library author, I'd like to present the case against bundling. These points should be fairly uncontroversial (if anyone disagrees let me know in the comments and I'll edit).

**Important caveat before we start:** I bundle. I'm a fan of bundling *in general*, it makes perfect sense for the work I do, and it generally has been a step forward. It has many positive aspects, my favorite being better closure compiler/rollup compression. But for the rest of this answer I'm only dwelling on potential flaws.

1. Bundling can lead to trivial cache misses. Any change to any part of your app invalidates the browser cache.
2. Bundling can make it harder to leverage a cache of common libraries. If you're using the same version of jquery from the same cdn as everyone else there's a good chance your users will never have to even hit your servers for it.
3. Bundling means that you generally are loading all of your JavaScript at once. There are exceptions like webpack code splitting but this complicates your build pipeline versus cating files.
4. Bundling means missing out on HTTP/2's ability to handle multiple asset requests in parallel. This may or may not be relevant to your use-case. If you're building an internal asset at FooCorp where everyone is still locked to IE 8 by IT because reasons this argument is uncompelling. Ditto most of your customer base being Chinese for the same reason. For *most* of the world, HTTP/2 is now [widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=http2) (chrome, firefox, edge, iOS safari). Meaning that you are giving the *majority* of your users a possibly sub-par experience.